# How do i serve Media files on production in Django in Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I currently have a Django site running on amazon lightsail,
i ran `python manage.py collectstatic` an had all static files running fine but i have issues with my media files..i can't upload to my project. Below are my codes

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/messages-http-vhost.conf  (edited also for messages-https-vhost.conf)

```
<IfDefine !IS_MESSAGES_LOADED>
    Define IS_MESSAGES_LOADED
    WSGIDaemonProcess messages python-home=/opt/bitnami/python python-path=/opt/bitnami/projects/messages
  </IfDefine>
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
    ServerAlias *
    WSGIProcessGroup messages
    Alias /robots.txt /opt/bitnami/projects/messages/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /opt/bitnami/projects/messages/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /opt/bitnami/projects/messages/static/
    Alias /media/ /opt/bitnami/projects/messages/media/
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/messages/static>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/messages/media>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/bitnami/projects/messages/messages/wsgi.py
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/messages/messages>
      <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
      </Files>
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

models.py

```
  message_audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/', null=True)
    message_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='message-pics/', null=True)
```

When i try to upload a file i get "Server Error (500)"

Comment: Check Apache's error log for the error message!

Comment: The error codes are overwhelming, i see wsgi:error, i also see ssl:warn, no clear description of what the issue is. @KlausD.

Answer (score 0):

use absolute path to media directory and make sure they have read and write permissions

```
message_audio = models.FileField(upload_to='/opt/bitnami/projects/messages/media/audio/', null=True)
message_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/opt/bitnami/projects/messages/media/message-pics/', null=True)
```